# Envers pulling back lots of data

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am currently auditing my db with envers and it's doing a great job. I have parsed various entities and show results in the UI which also works well.

I have now reached a problem with the performance. I am querying an entity to get a record and this query is taking about 5 seconds! Doing the SQL there appears to be many simple SQLs. The query seems to pull back a lot!

It's best explained with an example

My entity I am querying is `House`

This has a one to one with `Room` (yes odd example ;) )

My `House` has a field in with references the `Room`. The room does not know about a House at the DB level but does have a mappedBy field in hibernate.

Now Room also has other parameters, a list of furniture for example, a window and a door.

When I query house and call `House.getRoom().getId()` it appears like envers is then querying all the parameters inside Room as well. It will pull back all the furniture information, all the window information etc etc. All I want to audit is the Room so I will only compare simple parameters in Room like wallColour etc which are basic Strings or Integers.

My hibernate configuration is eagily and lazy fetching depending on the parameters but it looks like Envers is pulling everything.

Interestingly Ive discovered that if the relationship is reversed (where the Room entity has the House id) then when I call room.getHouse().getId() it doesnt pull everything.

Is this a querk of hibernate or how I am using it?

How can I get envers just to read what is in Room and then if I call getFurnitureList() is will then try and lazily load that rather than eagily?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I have been looking at projections and am wondering if I can use this just to return particular variables from this object. Does anyone know if this could solve my problem? I am still investigating them but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: All relations in Envers are lazy. So calling house.getRoom().getProperty() it should only do one query to get the room. However, getting the id should be possible without calling the DB. I don't understand how room.getHouse() is different than house.getRoom()?

Comment: @adamw thanks for the comment. do you know if envers takes into account the entity annotations? The difference between house.getRoom and room.getHouse is to do with where the relationship field is in the DB. I can update the question later with more details

Comment: yes, sure, Envers reads information from annotations (well, in fact it reads Hibernate metadata, which are combined xml/annotations data). As for house.getRoom/room.getHouse, I don't see where is the difference, as it seems both cases are identical except names ;)

Comment: @adamw The nnly difference is in the DB and the annotation in java. If I have a house which has a db column referencing a room then when I call house.getRoom() it seems to pull back a lot. If the room is referencing the house then when I call house.getRoom() it pulls back a small amount. It's quite odd!

Comment: maybe you have some code in hashcode/equals in some of the objects which causes the lazy relations to be read.

Comment: @adamw very good point. I'll check that tomorrow!